# Range restriction byte requirement

Tags: c, linker, linker-errors, rom

I have a linking error in a simple piece of code, and I know where the issue is.

```
long long maxClampRange(long maxClamp, long LoopGainFactor, long LoopGain)
{
    long long tempMax = (long long)maxClamp;
    long long tempMaxClamp;
    tempMaxClamp = (tempMax << 24);
    tempMaxClamp *= (long long)LoopGainFactor/LoopGain;

    return tempMaxClamp;
}
```

The line shift left by 24 causes the issue when tempMax is a 64 bit long long datatype.

What I am wondering, is how to calculate the amount of ROM that I need for this to link properly.

The actual error is

```
    lk166 E112: cannot locate 1 sections(s) 
    lk166 I455: requirement:0x10 bytes of ROM area in space spe:xc16x:code'
    lk166 I456: section type: ranged page restriction - any range of [0 .. 65536] with page alignment 65536 within range(s) 0xc0ba00-0xc0be00
```

I haven't figured out a way to break up the code that will make this work without using 32 bit long types. But, that causes everything to long work properly since it's not large enough to hold the shift.

Comment: Good luck finding a solution; I don't really understand the problem.  I think you should look hard at whether `a *= b/c;` produces the same answer as `a = (a * b) / c;` — and decide which answer you want.  Why is the ROM space limited to 16 bytes?  Can't you double it, and try again, or add more?  Or has your program simply grown too big and you have to remove code somewhere else?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is an embedded application, so I can't change any of these settings. It turned out to work just fine when I moved this piece of code to a .h file instead of a .c file. There's something in the linking stage that causes the error when it deals with 64 bit data types rather than 32. I actually tried doing all of this on one line, and only resorted to what you see in the example later on when I was trying to find out where the error was coming from. In any case, the code finally compiles correctly, although I have no idea why.